# Checking if encrypted username exists in sql database

Tags: sql-server, encryption

I have a table called login with a username and password both encrypted by using `ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE`

However when I insert a new login account I want to check wether the new login username doesn't exist already.

How can I check wether a username already exists in the database?

I've tried stuff like `select * from login where username = encryptbypassphrase('username', 'passphrase')` but that came out negative.

Comment: I think you have to swap username and passphrase: `select * from login where username = encryptbypassphrase('passphrase', 'username')` See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190357.aspx

Comment: You're right about that, Thanks. But in this example/question it doesn't matter since I do the same encrypt to insert and to check wether a user exists.

Comment: In which field do you store the result of the encryptopn?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would expect something like these to be used:

```
--- For INSERT
insert into login
  (username, encryptedphrase)
values
  ('username', encryptbypassphrase('username', 'passphrase'))

--- Checking a specific username, passphrase combination:
select * 
from login 
where username = 'username' 
  and encryptedphrase = 
      encryptbypassphrase(username, 'passphrase')

--- Checking if a specific username already exists:
select exists
       ( select * 
         from login 
         where username = 'username' 
       ) userexists
```

Comment: Username is encrypted. So saying "username = 'username'" doesn't work.

Comment: So, you actually store only the `encryptbypassphrase('username', 'passphrase')` ?